# Most commonly occuring combination in a list of integer array

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, combinations

I have a list of integer array, where each array have some numbers sorted.
Here I want to find the most commonly occurring combination of sequence of integers based on all the array.
For example if the list of array is as follows

```
A1 - 1 2 3 5 7 8
A2 - 2 3 5 6 7
A3 - 3 5 7 9
A4 - 1 2 3 7 9
A5 - 3 5 7 10
```

Here

```
{3,5,7} - {A1,A3,A5}
{2,3}   - {A1,A2,A4}
```

The above is a set of input and desired output.
How can i do this most efficiently in Java?

Comment: Nothing good came to mind. Sorting the array should definitely help. Performance is a bug hurdle here. Or else some set operation might have helped.

Comment: Have you looked at any algorithms.

Comment: First you should try to solve the problem, then see if it is causing performance issues.

Comment: Why is the answer not `{3, 5} - {A1,A2,A3,A5}`? Or even `{3} - {A1,A2,A3,A4,A5}`?

Comment: Yes , {3,5} is a match . {3} cant be taken as the size is just one. AM looking for size more than 1

Comment: Also {3,5} comes inside {3,5,7} , so not taking. Am looking for the highest subset.

Comment: So you want to find the longest common combination, instead of the most commonly ocurring combination? {3,5} occurs more commonly than {3,5,7}.

Comment: I want to find all such combination with size more than 1

Comment: Why {7,9} and {1,2,3} aren't outputs, then? I think you should better define what exactly is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Сreate new two-dimensional array(with two rows). In first row write all value which be in other arrays, for example A1 and A2 = {1 2 3 5 6 7 8}. Then go to array and calculate the sum of the elements encountered and put this sum in the corresponding element of the array. Thereafter just analyze an array.

Comment: Are you telling to create all cominations of A1,A2,A3,A4 and then based on its stat , find the combination ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I did not understand your question correctly. If you need to enter 3 5 7 and get A1, A2, A3 I think you need use a list. For example:

```
ArrayList<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>();
test.add(1);
test.add(2);
ArrayList<Integer> tesdt2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
tesdt2.add(1);
tesdt2.add(2);
boolean a = test.containsAll(tesdt2); //true
test.add(3);
```

If you need to use standard array (Integer []myArray = new Integer[n];) you need to write your function which go for all arrays and find needed element. Something like this:

```
boolean search(Integer []A1,Integer []array2){
int tmp = -1;
for(int i=0;i<A1.length;i++){
for(int j=0;j<array2.length;j++){
if(A1[j] == array2[i]){
tmp++;


}
            }
            if(tmp!=i){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```